# How to send CoAP requests with Python?

Tags: python, http, iot, coap

Is there a way to send CoAP requests, like HTTP requests, using Python. I tried below one but I got many errors.

```
rec = reuest.get(coap://localhost:5683/other/block)
```

Comment: I assume you meant `requests.get`? (from the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library). Be sure to edit to clarify, and include the error message you got for reference of future visitors. It isn't really relevant to the solution **this time**, but a [mcve] is always helpful to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library such as [CoAPython](https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon) to act as a CoAP client:

```
from coapthon.client.helperclient import HelperClient

client = HelperClient(server=('127.0.0.1', 5683))
response = client.get('other/block')
client.stop()
```

The `response` is of type [`Response`](https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon/blob/master/coapthon/messages/response.py). The methods available on the response are listed in the documentation, which you must [build yourself](https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon#build-the-documentation).

Since you haven't listed what you want to do with the response, you can use the documentation to find out the methods available and get the values you want.